# Android Interstitial Ad - how will I know Google cannot serve more ads in certain markets?

Tags: android, ads, interstitial

I'm working on an Android app, and would like to show ads in the free version of the app. My plan is to limit the user's time on the free version if there are no sufficient amount of ads coming from Google.

I'm able to check the user's connectivity to the internet and limit the user's time on the app if the user is not connected, however, I don't know what kind of error message should I expect from Google if no ads are available in certain markets, or does Google always serve ads in all markets?

I implemented the ad based on the Google documentation:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial?hl=en-US

Thanks for your thoughts on this.

Comment: What do you mean what kind of Error ? the link you posted already have a callback method `onAdFailedToLoad` which has a `LoadAdError` object which has the [Error response](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/ad-load-errors) . And [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#constant-summary) is the Error code list .

Comment: @ADM, I can't find an error message for this scenario (no ads served for this market)

Comment: That might be `ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL`.